# Passing authenticated ASP.NET Identity user from MVC to Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I have a dashboarding application which is made up of an ASP.NET MVC5 presentation layer, and a Web API which serves data (via ajax calls from JavaScript in the host app).

The app is hosted in IIS with the front end MVC app set as an application, and the Web API app as a sub folder (also an IIS application).

So my app runs http://dashboards/app/
and makes calls to http://dashboards/app/api/... for data.

If I set both apps to be secured by Windows Authentication in IIS then I can read the logged in username in both the host app and the Web API.

I have a new requirement that we have external user accounts, so I have set up my MVC app to use ASP.NET Identity, copying the base code that is supplied in the sample when creating a new MVC 5 project.  This works fine for the MVC host app, I log in, read the logged in username and can see my dashboard but ajax calls to the Web API project fail as they can no longer see a user.  HttpContext.Current.User.Identity is null and IsAuthenticated is false.

From my research so far this is because my MVC site is using a cookie based authentication method:

```
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        {....
```

but the Web API is stateless and is looking for Authorization headers.

How do I set up my child Web API app to be able to read the logged in user from the parent app?